# Matlab code to Python code Conversion ( Using data frames)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matlab, data-conversion

So I am working on changing a Matlab code to python code, for visualizing a graph. This code is basically used working on data from radar signals. Here is the Matlab code.

```
data1 = csvread('degree45_rd1_sitstill_0305.csv');  
rd1_data = data1(:,2:end);
rd1_nor = abs(rd1_data);
radarResolution = 0.0522; 
radarDataTimes = data1(:,1);
% plot raw data
fs = floor((length(radarDataTimes)-1)/(radarDataTimes(end)- radarDataTimes(1)));
ts = 1/fs;
t = (0:length(rd1_nor(:,1))-1)/fs;
dist_rd1 = (0:length(rd1_nor(1,:))-1)*radarResolution;
figure;
contour(dist_rd1,t,rd1_nor);
title('Radar 1 raw data plot'); ylabel('Time (s)'); xlabel('Distance (m)');
```

Here is the change code in Python, i am in doubt that if I am getting **fs** right or not, or applying loops is right and wrong.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import numpy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

print(df)

rd1_data =df.iloc[:, 1:]
print(rd1_data)
print(np.shape(rd1_data))

a = numpy.asarray(rd1_data)
print(np.shape(a))

arr = []

i = 0
for v in a:
arr.append([])
for x in v:
arr[i].append(abs(complex(x)))
i+=1
print(arr)


data = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(data)



radar_datatime = df.iloc[:,0]

print(radar_datatime)
import math
radarResolution = 0.0522
fs = math.floor(len(radar_datatime)-1)/(radar_datatime[180]-radar_datatime[0])
print(fs)
ts = 1/fs
print(ts)


print(np.shape(arr))


t = [((val[0]-1)/fs) for val in arr]
print(t)
print(np.shape(t))
dist_rd1 = [((val-1)*radarResolution) for val in arr[0]]
print(dist_rd1)
print(np.shape(dist_rd1))

data_t=data.iloc[:,:]
print(data_t)





import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contour(dist_rd1,t,arr)
plt.savefig("/Users/fateh/Documents/my_file.png")
plt.show()
```

So just to verify if I edited the python code right or wrong. Need to find the best solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you have way overcomplicated this. 
I am not sure what your raw data file looks like, I have made a synthetic map to test your code out. I am not entirely sure of the operations you are trying to do here.

I have translated the Matlab code in place for you. Check the operations being made especially the calculation of t. (UNLESS you actually want to / by ts rather than fs like the example has).

So I am not sure this is exactly what you want but it does a thing!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data1 = pd.readcsv('degree45_rd1_sitstill_0305.csv') 
#Synthetic Data:
data1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000,size=(5,10)))

rd1_data = data1.iloc[:,1:-1]
#Changed to 1:-1 as index in Matlab stat at 1 compared to 0 in python
rd1_nor = abs(rd1_data)
radarResolution = 0.0522
radarDataTimes = data1.iloc[:,0]

# plot raw data
fs = np.floor((len(radarDataTimes)-1)/(radarDataTimes.iloc[-1]- radarDataTimes[0]))
ts = 1/fs

t = len((rd1_nor.iloc[:,1])-1)
t=np.arange(0,t) #/ts
#/fs doesn't want to work. Not sure if its something with my synthetic dataset though or if want to / fs or ts.

dist_rd1 = len((rd1_nor.iloc[1,:])-1)
dist_rd1=np.arange(0,dist_rd1)*radarResolution

plt.contourf(dist_rd1,t,rd1_nor);
plt.title('Radar 1 raw data plot')
plt.ylabel('Time (s)')
plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
```

Comment: fs= 17 as i am taking 17 frames per second and but if i hardcode by putting a fs=17, i get a blank graph and why do we have two t and two dist_rd1 variables.

Comment: I can't really help you without seeing your data. There are two t's and two dist_rd1's for clarity. The first calculates the length and then the second makes a range between 0 and the length, same as what the matlab code did; I just used two lines for clarity. Uncomment the 't=np.arange(0,t) #/ts' if you do want to divide here, I think you do. And use the correct Data1 at the top. A few prints() may help with your debugging. I am also not sure if order of operations is out on `fs=np.floor`

Comment: hey its working now, I made changes in it. But my graph isn't that clear. Is there any difference between Contour graph in Matlab and Python.

Comment: maybe to do with the colour map you are using? Also try use plt.colorbar(). I used contourf (filled) here (rather than contour), which shouldnt be too different to contour on matlab but am not entirely sure. You can also try plt.pcolormesh or plt.imshow as well. Can also try set plt.contourf(x,y,z,levels=20) or something to get more contours might also help you. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html